# Is there a way to backup emails from OWA

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-client, outlook-web-access

I am using OWA on IE8 and am do not have any email client like outlook installed.
We just access email in the browser using OWA.
Is there a script (maybe a scraper) that backs up the emails?

How do I go about writing such a script, is there a OWA API?

I googled a lot but every solution first syncs OWA to exchange or outlook or some other email client and then backs it up. I do not have that luxury.

I have python installed, so a simple email client script written in python can be helpful too, if it can somehow be configured to logina nd read emails from OWA.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you install Outlook? This would save you a lot of time and potential data loss using other methods... When you say "we", is this a company or individuals? I ask because it can help us justify the answer if cost is a restriction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into the weboutlook package from Holovaty. I have not tried it, but here is it: https://code.google.com/p/weboutlook/source/browse/trunk/weboutlook/scraper.py?r=2

```
"""
Microsoft Outlook Web Access scraper

Retrieves full, raw e-mails from Microsoft Outlook Web Access by
screen scraping. Can do the following:

* Log into a Microsoft Outlook Web Access account with a given username
  and password.
* Retrieve all e-mail IDs from the first page of your Inbox.
* Retrieve the full, raw source of the e-mail with a given ID.
* Delete an e-mail with a given ID (technically, move it to the "Deleted
  Items" folder).

The main class you use is OutlookWebScraper. See the docstrings in the code
and the "sample usage" section below.

This module does no caching. Each time you retrieve something, it does a fresh
HTTP request. It does cache your session, though, so that you only have to log
in once.
"""
```

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill the essential parts? Well, that there is a python module that does this for you. Do you want me to copy paste the code? That does not make sense to me and it might invole ¢ issues.

Comment: You could say what the script does as a minimum. That is in the header of the source code ...